# .NET Configuring GIT environment and local build for working with multiple repositories with dependencies between them

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2012, build

We have multiple teams working together on a large project divided to multiple repositories , each team works on one or more repositories , some of the repositories are shared among the teams.
As a security policy , we dont give a developer access to all repositories but only ones that are required for his project.
Currently our dev folder looks like this :

```
Repos.Folder
  Repo1
  Repo2
  ...
  RepoN
  bin.folder
```

The developer first download from the build server all the dlls to the bin folder, all projects output is to that bin.folder as well on local build through visual studio .

The problem is , that because not all developers have all projects , we cannot reference projects to .csproj files (as not everyone would have those references) , but we reference them to dll files in the bin folder - so all developers can download them from the build server, AND SO , when a developer tries to setup a work space solution (.sln file) , visual studio does not automatically detects the build order of the projects , so each developer needs to setup the sln file himself by going through each one of the projects references -- which is a tremendous overhead ...

Wanted to ask if someone has a solution for that problem or if someone spots a caveat/problem in our dev env and know how to handle it better.

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would question if the security gain in preventing some developers access to some code really outweighs the problems it causes.

But, assuming the given situation, I would consider using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/):

Each project could publish it's own NuGet package, preferably [using a build server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NuGet) that produces a unique semantic version for each build and package (Ideally also coupled to a version number from the version control system).

You can publish the NuGet packages to an internal feed (e.g. [a file share or an internally hosted NuGet server](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)).

The NuGet packages can have dependencies that reflect the dependencies between the projects. You probably don't want to have the projects in the same solution anymore.

This way the dependencies between the projects become totally independent of the actual source code. You also don't have to version control any binaries. Rather, the exact versions that a particular code depends on is clear from reading the version number from the `packages.config` file. This also makes version control and merging of code easier. It also makes the projects less coupled and the resulting components more reusable.

A drawback to note, however, is that modifying a dependency and then consuming it in another project will become more cumbersome. The most straightforward path will be to update the NuGet package using the build server and then updating the NuGet package in the consuming project.